# How to order the support of proposals with dependent Likert scale data?

Tags: repeated-measures, modeling, likert

For my thesis I wanted to examine the support for 6 proposals to make diets at my university more sustainable.

For example:

1. Protein based on insects
2. Reduced meat consumption
3. Plant based subsitutes
4. ...

To measure the support of each proposal I used a 5-point Likert scales (1 = Strongly disagree, 2 = Disagree, 3 = Neutral, 4 = Agree, 5 = Strongly agree).

Example of output:

[image]

Now I want to order the proposals by the level of support. Mean scores and medians give an indication of the order of support. But I want to know which differences are significant. Since Likert scale data are ordered-categorical I used Kruskal–Wallis one-way analysis of variance, which revealed a significant difference between proposals. Then I used pairwise Wilcoxon Rank Sum tests as post-hoc test to identify which proposals differ significantly (p-adjusted = Bonferroni). So I was able to order the proposals:

Level of support: Proposal 1 & 4 > proposal 2, 3 & 5 > proposal 6

However, the samples for all proposal are the same (dependent samples), so I'm confused whether the methods I used are suitable for this goal, and I would like some feedback.

Comment: If your data were dependent, you should have use Friedman's test, not the Kruskal-Wallis.

Comment: Thanks.

So the ID of the respondents should be considered as 'blocks'? I used the Friedman's test. As a post-hoc I used pairwise Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test based on this website: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/friedman-test-using-spss-statistics.php. 

Based on the output the proposals can be ordered similarly: 
proposal 1 & 4 > proposal 2, 3 & 5 > proposal 6